# Como simular um clique de botão no swift (para MAC OSX)

Tags: swift, osx, mac

Estou fazendo um programa para Mac e preciso encontrar uma maneira de "clicar" num botão a partir de um código.

Estou tentando colocar este código em um outro botão e já tentei isso das 3 seguintes maneiras:

```
func mouseDown(_ NSButton1: NSEvent) { }
```

```
func performClick(_ NSButton1: NSEvent) { }
```

```
Button1.sendActionsForControlEvents(NSControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Poderia editar a sua pergunta e postar juntamente o código daquilo que você já tentou? Aproveite também para dar uma vista de olhos à página [**Como Perguntar**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) que vai ajudá-lo a construir melhor a sua pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Se você quiser definir o que vai acontecer com um botão depois que clicar nele, basta fazer conectar o botão do Storyboard ao código, escolher o tipo de Connection como Action. Assim, uma nova função será criada, por exemplo:

```
@IBAction func sampleFunction(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

Agora, dentro dos colchetes, escreva as ações que você quer. Por exemplo:

```
@IBAction func sampleFunction(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Você clicou em mim!!")
}
```

Nesse caso, toda vez que você clicar no botão, a string "Você clicou em mim!" será "printada" no XCode.